# Unbounded representations of Banach algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Can a representation of a Banach algebra be unbounded?

To clarify, I'm not asking about a representation as unbounded operators, but
rather a homomorphism $\pi: A \to B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$, with the property
that $\sup_{a \neq 0} \frac{\|\pi(a)\|}{\|a\|} = \infty$.

This question is inspired by chapter 2.5 of Arveson's *Spectral Theory*, which proves that every representation of a Banach *-algebra is contractive.  This raises the question of what happens when a Banach algebra does not have an (isometric) involution, or when a homomorphism does not respect it.

I know of examples of unbounded homomorphisms of Banach algebras (the simplest: if $E$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, turn both $E$ and $\mathbb{C}$ into Banach algebras by defining all products to be zero, and any unbounded functional on $E$ will become an unbounded homomorphism), but none in which the codomain is $B(H)$.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused: isn't your example of an unbounded homomorphism from $E$ to $\mathbb{C}$ also an example of the kind you want? Can't you compose your homomorphism with the isometric embedding $\mathbb{C}\to B(H)$ obtained by sending $1$ to the identity operator?

Comment: This imbedding won't be a homomorphism because $\mathbb C$ was endowed with an unusual product rule in this construction.

Comment: @fedja: thanks, you a right -- but then if you pick a nonzero operator $T\in B(H)$ with $T^2=0$, the map from $\mathbb{C}$ with zero multiplication sending $1$ to $T$ is a homomorphism?  Then what I wrote works fine.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder what can be done in the semisimple case?

Comment: Usually, an unbounded operator from a Banach space (such as your Banach algebra $A$) to another Banach space (in this case $B(H)$) refers to a densely defined map. Such a map is often required to have closed graph. It seems unnatural to consider everywhere-defined unbounded maps $A\to B(H)$, as those have no chance of having a closed graph.

Comment: This kind of question is sometimes referred to as an "automatic continuity" problem, since one is asking for conditions on a domain or codomain algebra ensuring that a homomorphism between Banach algebras is automatically continuous. Off the top of my head, I don't recall results where the codomain is $B(H)$, but will think about this some more

Comment: André: But it does seem natural to consider whether such everywhere-defined unbounded homomorphisms exist on a given Banach algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dima Shlyakhtenko indicated, there are examples, obtained for example by modifying your zero product example to $x\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}0&f(x)\\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ for some unbounded linear functional $f$.

A generalization of the result you mentioned is found in Theorem 4.1.20 of Rickart's *General theory of Banach algebras*.  A special case of that theorem says that if the range of the representation is a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$, then the representation is automatically continuous.

What looks like a good reference is Dales's *[Banach algebras and automatic continuity](http://books.google.com/books?id=WZ6DQgAACAAJ)*, but I don't currently have a copy.  It is referenced in an *Encyclopaedia of mathematics* article by the same author called "[Automatic continuity for Banach algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=47YC2h295JUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false)," which also gives some other references that might help.  According to the article, there are some Banach spaces $E$ such that every homomorphism from $B(E)$ to another Banach algebra is continuous.  (It doesn't say which ones.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  Dales's book doesn't have many results for representations, but here are some items of interest:
--Thm 5.1.4: Every simple representation (no invariant subspaces) of a Banach algebra on a normed space is continuous.
--Cor 5.4.12: Homomorphisms from $B(E)$ are continuous if $E \simeq E \oplus E$. 
--Many basic questions are still open, like automatic continuity of homomorphisms from $C^*$-algebras to Banach algebras if the codomain is another $C^*$-algebra or the map is surjective.  --Automatic continuity of maps from $C(\Omega)$ depends on the continuum hypothesis.
